# Getting Registered Owner in C# returns unknown value

Tags: c#, registry

I am trying to get the values of RegisteredOwner and RegisteredOrganization in a C# WinForms application and it keeps returning the default value, unknown and I am not too sure why.

```
string Owner  = "";
        string Company = "";

        OperatingSystem osInfo = System.Environment.OSVersion;
        if ( osInfo.Platform == PlatformID.Win32Windows )
        {
            // Windows 98                                                
            Owner   = (string)Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion", "RegisteredOwner", "Unknown");
            Company = (string)Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion", "RegisteredOrganization", "Unknown");
        }
        else if (osInfo.Platform == PlatformID.Win32NT)
        {
            // for NT+                
            Owner   = (string)Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion", "RegisteredOwner", "Unknown");
            Company = (string)Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion", "RegisteredOrganization", "Unknown");            
            // do you need admin to read?  or just write?  b/c you need the UAC elevation.  so out it on the Save button if it is just save changes, or in manifest.               
        }

        lblRegOwner.Text = Owner;            
        lblRegOrg.Text = Company;
```

I tried running the program as admin with same results, and using a standard command prompt I am able to get the value returned.

`C:\Users\jweinraub>reg query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\windows nt\currentversion" /v registeredowner`

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\windows nt\currentversion
    registeredowner    REG_SZ    Jonathan Weinraub`

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.openbasekey(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Which version of windows? Just tested this via copy paste on Windows 7 x64, x86, any cpu build using .net 4.5.1 and it works correctly.

Comment: Windows 10 x64 is where I am currently running this.  Interesting, I just made it an x64 and it seems to have done the trick.  However, it isn't a program that really requires it so I like for it to run on either architecture without maintaining separate binaries, so a check on say `bool is64 = System.Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
string Owner = "";
string Company = "";

OperatingSystem osInfo = System.Environment.OSVersion;
if (osInfo.Platform == PlatformID.Win32Windows)
{
    // Windows 98                                                
    Owner = Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion", "RegisteredOwner", "Unknown").ToString();
    Company = Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion", "RegisteredOrganization", "Unknown").ToString();
}
else if (osInfo.Platform == PlatformID.Win32NT)
{
    // for NT+                
    RegistryKey localKey;
    if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
        localKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);
    else
        localKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32);

    Owner = localKey.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion").GetValue("RegisteredOwner", "Unknown").ToString();
    Company = localKey.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion").GetValue("RegisteredOrganization", "Unknown").ToString();
}

lblRegOwner.Text = Owner;
lblRegOrg.Text = Company;
```

Comment: That seemed to have done the trick, I was having some issues earlier with using Owner/Company as objects and despite casting the string, I somehow was overloading GetValue, but I think the documentation I was reading was much older... but thank you!!